# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “images” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=http://

Tags: ios, swift, imageurl

```
func loadCell(personObj:Person){
    self.lblTitle.text = personObj.title
    self.lblDesc.text = personObj.desc
    print("ImgUrlInCell:", personObj.imageUrl)
    do {
        self.imgPicture.image = try UIImage(data:NSData(contentsOf:NSURL(string: personObj.imageUrl) as! URL) as Data)
    } catch {
        print("Error:",error)
    }
}
```

Firstly, I've parsed data from API and put it in object and then insert it into database. At the time of displaying data I fetched them from database and list them in Tableview. 
**If there is an internet connection everything is working fine**
**If there is no internet connection image url doesn't work, It prints error 6 times. (I have 10 images in database or API)**
**Also, There are 10 image url displaying in console in ImgUrlInCell:**
Please someone help me with this issue. What have I wronged.

Comment: If your displaying cell or visible cell are 6 then there will be 6 errors. Cell are reusable so it will take memory only of visible cells. It is not an issue

Answer (score -2):

You are using `TableView` and in `TableView` as per screen size and `Cell` size, it will show max cell in your screens so it may be possible that in your case its loading **6 cells** data and all 6 cells have load image method so its throwing error 6 times.

To load Images lazily there are many famous libraries which will manage single time download and cache that image.

**SDWebImage** is one of the best libraries fits for your problem.

Link : [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

And follow below code to get Image from the server.

**Swift:**

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Put an above line of code in your `loadCell` method with your imageURL.

Please check Internet connection by using Apple Reachability classes and load your image if the Internet connection is there.

**Edit:**

For Locally storing image you can use below function of SDWebImage Downloader and cache your image before showing it to the user.

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().imageDownloader?.downloadImage(with: NSURL(string: strURL) as URL!, options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.continueInBackground, progress: {
                (receivedSize, ExpectedSize, imageURL) in
                print("receive:",receivedSize,"Expected:",ExpectedSize,"Image URL:",imageURL ?? "No URL")
            }, completed: {
                (image, data, error, finished) in
                print("Image Data:",data ?? "No Data")
                // Do your stuff to store downloaded image
            })
```

Link : [Reachability Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Web image is displayed well in all cell when there is internet connection. I didn't understand still.

Comment: Ok so for that you have to use reachability classes and check if Internet connection is there load image otherwise load place holder or default image.

Comment: I'm not getting your point. I've already checked the network connection in view controller. If there is internet connection api gives imageurl string to database and database gives gives us that string and is displayed well. If no internet connection database still gives the same imageurl string. I've logged it in console. But not displayed it in cell.

Comment: You have check network connection in your viewDidLoad() now if there is no internet connection you are still fetching data from DB and show it on screen kind of Offline data and Images are coming from server and for that you need Internet connection so you have to put condition code in LoadCell method if Internet connection is there you will download Image data and if no will show default image over there in cell.

Comment: So if there is no internet connection it is not possible to show the image that is fetched from local database? Is there any solution to show images in offline mode?

Comment: yes SD web images doing same thats why i propose it its fetching images from server while user connected with internet and store it locally and next time it will show only from local Please check it once.

Comment: SDWebImage is loading the image of visible part only. If I do not scroll down and load all images once in online mode. Then the remote images (i.e. images below the screen) do not load in offline mode. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Please check updated answer I have added Download image code through SDWebImage without showing it to user you can cache your image while user is online.

Comment: I've url in string variabled object. How can I use that url in NSURL(string: strURL). If I use that url in place of strURL then following error is occuring.
cannot convert value of type (any, any, string?)->() to expected argument type sdwebimage

Comment: Can you post some code so i can get some idea what kind of error you are getting ?

Comment: I've pasted my code above but its saying someting like peer reviewed. I'm not sure whether you get that or not.

Comment: Hey CodeChanger I am unable to edit my question. I want to describe here. I've pasted your suggested code in loadCell method. I've product object containing image url. How do I use your code?

Comment: hello codechanger here is my edited code in another link. please answer in here if you have time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784672/image-did-not-load-below-the-visible-area-of-uitableviewcell-while-doing-image-c